# org.opensaml.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBuilder when running on Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat8, opensaml

I have a saml project based on opensaml which is running OK on tomcat7. Our company is upgrading to tomcat8 and I can't run it. The error message is

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBuilder

I did some research online and some articles say it may be the reason I mix using opensaml 2 and 3. However, I only use opensaml 3. Here is the pom.xml and error log

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>                
        </dependency>
```

Stacktrace:

> 2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBuilder
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.initializeObjectProviders(XMLConfigurator.java:238)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:203)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:188)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:162)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:52)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(XMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:45)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.323-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize(InitializationService.java:56)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at com.vmware.eucenablement.saml.service.SAMLIDPService.(SAMLIDPService.java:27)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at com.vmware.samltoolkit.idp.IDPService.(IDPService.java:43)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at com.jpmchase.gca.idp.GcaIDP.initIDPService(GcaIDP.java:43)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at com.jpmchase.gca.StartStopListener.InitIDP(StartStopListener.java:69)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at com.jpmchase.gca.StartStopListener.contextInitialized(StartStopListener.java:42)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.324-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1129)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1871)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   2019-05-02T15:12:06.325-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Can somebody give some help? Thanks a lot

Comment: Change your last dependency...  FYI, OpenSAML 2.x will be the xmltooling, openws and opensaml2 jars.  3.x will be entirely opensaml-<modulename> jars with 3.x.x version numbers. Last response at the bottom from [here](http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/Opensaml-Classpath-issues-td7638136.html)